# FAMD explained variance of components very low

Tags: categorical-data, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I am dealing with a dataset composed of 50 features. There are both categorical (some with many levels, others dichotomous) and numerical features, so I decided to use FAMD in order to reduce the number of components.
Trying to build 3 components, the explained variance is:

- First Component: 0.00613
- Second Component: 0.00426
- Third Component: 0.00351

The total sum is 0.013, which is very far from 1!
Adding more components, the results are the same.

I am using the ***prince*** library in Python to evaluate FAMD and using the explained_inertia_ function.
Here is the documentation:  https://github.com/MaxHalford/prince

How to deal with this? How to improve the explained variance with few components?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my dataset. The sum of the explained variance (explained_inertia_) won't add up to 1 unless you specify when instantiating the FAMD() class with the parameter n_components on the same size as the number of variables you are fitting to it. See this link: https://pythonlang.dev/repo/maxhalford-prince/

Also, even when I specified the n_components with the same amount of variables, the explained_inertia_ still wouldn't add to 1. I think this behavior is due to the fact that you fit the FAMD() with raw categorical variables and the algorithm uses the Pandas get_dummies() method to encode those features, thus increasing the total amount of features of your dataset. Here is an example using the documentation data.

```
import pandas as pd
from prince import FAMD
X = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        ['A', 'A', 'A', 2, 5, 7, 6, 3, 6, 7],
        ['A', 'A', 'A', 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3],
        ['B', 'A', 'B', 5, 2, 1, 1, 7, 1, 1],
        ['B', 'A', 'B', 7, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        ['B', 'B', 'B', 3, 5, 6, 5, 2, 6, 6],
        ['B', 'B', 'A', 3, 5, 4, 5, 1, 7, 5]
    ],
    columns=['E1 fruity', 'E1 woody', 'E1 coffee',
             'E2 red fruit', 'E2 roasted', 'E2 vanillin', 'E2 woody',
             'E3 fruity', 'E3 butter', 'E3 woody'],
    index=['Wine {}'.format(i+1) for i in range(6)]
)

famd = FAMD(n_components=10, random_state=123)
famd.fit(X)
famd.explained_inertia_.sum()
```

Which gives us:

```
0.9999999999999997
```

I know that's really really close to one even though I specified the n_components=10 which is the same amount of features. But when I tested this approach on my dataset with is comprised of 20+ columns and 3,000,000 data points the explained variance wouldn't add up to 1.

So in order to check the amount of features you can just call the famd.column_correlations() method:

```
famd.column_correlations(X)
```

Which gives us:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5
E1 coffee_A -0.638646   0.054793    -0.357563   0.144806    -0.428958   0.207656
E1 coffee_B 0.638646    -0.054793   0.357563    -0.144806   0.428958    -0.207656
E1 fruity_A -0.398058   -0.377338   -0.430546   -0.126795   -0.237398   0.533383
E1 fruity_B 0.398058    0.377338    0.430546    0.126795    0.237398    -0.533383
E1 woody_A  0.527092    -0.925287   0.327178    -0.451342   0.374655    0.023936
E1 woody_B  -0.527092   0.925287    -0.327178   0.451342    -0.374655   -0.023936
E2 red fruit    0.898924    -0.494724   0.885217    -0.064772   0.862051    -0.678653
E2 roasted  -0.981521   0.703908    -0.836953   0.414603    -0.767083   0.577307
E2 vanillin -0.942450   0.536364    -0.968898   0.324330    -0.813833   0.843984
E2 woody    -0.940691   0.779423    -0.862575   0.587997    -0.915200   0.686830
E3 butter   -0.967765   0.802784    -0.749318   0.570645    -0.760397   0.466162
E3 fruity   0.598539    -0.782967   0.285297    -0.972318   0.321592    -0.098479
E3 woody    -0.965233   0.707537    -0.932395   0.524883    -0.888048   0.781353
```

That's 13 variables now and keep in mind I didn't run any preprocessing to the data. So changing the n_components parameter to 13 gives us:

```
0.9999999999999999
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The thing here is that I want the algorithm to run FAMD on 3 components because the intent was to plot these three dimensions. Then, the challenge here is to improve the explainability with the same number of components, if possible!